# Can I define custom voice interaction with the Google Voice Interaction API

Tags: android, google-voice, google-voice-actions

After hours of research I still cannot answer the question whether one can define custom interactions for an app with the google voice interaction api.

As an example I would like that my Android App can answer questions like

> OK Google - what is my remaining balance in MyCustomApp?

As I understood from https://developers.google.com/voice-actions/custom-actions the current state is that no one can define custom actions anymore or is this information not up to date anymore? Thus we have to stick to the predefined system actions?

Comment: If you are limited to on device resources - then I believe you are looking at the current state. Note that a separate Actions on Google exists for integration with Google Assistant https://developers.google.com/actions/develop/conversation